# WixRemoveFoldersEx appears to be firing during both install and uninstall

Tags: wix, wix3

I'm using Wix 3.11.4510.0
During the Install we see the error in the log. It appears to be doing no harm as I don't believe that is actually firing . We are geting calls from customers asking

Thanks
Michae

```
    <ComponentGroup Id="UnInstallCleanUp" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
        <Component Id="UnInstallCleanUp" Guid="{908C5D26-8379-4E62-86F8-26C9F0409EAA}">
            <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="Software\xxxxxxxxxsx\PublicReadable" Name="Path" Type="string" Value="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]"  KeyPath="yes"/>
            <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
```

This occurs

```
Action ended 12:29:39: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 12:29:39: WixRemoveFoldersEx.
MSI (s) (38!1C) [12:29:40:112]: Closing MSIHANDLE (7) of type 790531 for thread 5148
MSI (s) (38!1C) [12:29:40:112]: Closing MSIHANDLE (3) of type 790541 for thread 5148
MSI (s) (38!1C) [12:29:40:114]: Closing MSIHANDLE (6) of type 790531 for thread 5148
MSI (s) (38!1C) [12:29:40:114]: Closing MSIHANDLE (5) of type 790540 for thread 5148
WixRemoveFoldersEx:  Error 0x80070057: Missing folder property: APPLICATIONFOLDER for row: wrfD426C0E3317774F55FB79E7BF0E43C1F
MSI (s) (38:A8) [12:29:40:116]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2) of type 790542 for thread 8540
CustomAction WixRemoveFoldersEx returned actual error code 1603 but will be translated to success due to continue marking
MSI (s) (38:5C) [12:29:40:117]: Doing action: CostInitialize
MSI (s) (38:5C) [12:29:40:117]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 12:29:40: WixRemoveFoldersEx. Return value 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WixRemoveFoldersEx` custom action runs during every operation, to determine if it has work to do. The log message is to indicate that the property isn't set and it couldn't do any work even if there were work to do.